# (Java) How to cancel the timer immediately when some condition is met

Tags: java, timer

**The Program**
My program asks **three** math questions such as 10+5?
It shows one question at a time on the console. Users answers via the command-line and have **5 seconds to answer**. The next question would show **only** when the user answers the question correctly **or** when the time is up.

Once the user answers the question correctly within the given time, the next question needs to show (it shouldn't wait until the time is up). The timer should should continue and **not restart** when the user answers the question wrong. The timer restarts **only** when the next question shows.

**The problems**
The program does not immediately cancel the timer after the user    answered the question correctly.
Also, the next question would not    show up even when the time is up; users have to input something in    order to continue to the next question.
Lastly, The next question would    also show when users enter an incorrect answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask; 
import java.util.Random;
/** 
 *Simple count down timer demo of java.util.Timer facility.
 */

/*
 * start timer
 * cancel when isLastMoveValid == true
 * start timer again soon
 * */

public class Countdown {
    public static double i = 5;
    public static int answer;
    static Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rand = new Random(); 
    static int num1;
    static int num2;
    static int questionNo = 3;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (questionNo >0) {
            num1 = rand.nextInt(11); 
            num2 = rand.nextInt(11);
            callTimer();       
            System.out.println(num1+ "+" + num2 + "?");
            answer = inputs.nextInt();
        }

    } // end of main method

    public static void callTimer() {

         final Timer timer = new Timer();
         i = 6;

         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {          
             public void run() {
                 i -= 0.001;

                 if (i< 0 || answer == num1 + num2) {
                     questionNo--;              
                     timer.cancel();                
                 }

             } // end of run
         }, 0, 1); // end of scheduleAtFixedRate



    } // end of callTimer
}
```

Comment: Rather than timer, I'd recommend a `ScheduledExecutorService`, but the approach is similar. You get a `ScheduledFuture` Object back when you schedule the task, which you can call #cancel on. Using this, you can simply schedule what happens after 5 seconds pass and cancel it if you have to (e.g. on input)

Comment: Possible duplicates for the timeout part: [set timeout for user's input](//stackoverflow.com/q/10059068) or [How do I call some blocking method with a timeout in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1164301) or [Time limit for an input](//stackoverflow.com/q/5853989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your **timer object as a field**, so you can **access** it at any time. See the cancel method how to cancel. If you want to restart the timer, you must create a new object of the timer and the timertask, because they get discarded with the thread.

See documentation on Timer.cancel method:

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.Does
>   not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).Once a
>   timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminatesgracefully,
>   and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

For example something like this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest
{
    private Timer timer;

    public void cancelTimer()
    {
        this.timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("Canceled timer!");
    }

    public void startTimer()
    {
        // once a timertask is canceled, you can not restart it
        // because the thread is deleted. So we need to create a 
        // new object of a timer and a timertask.
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Hello there!");
            }
        };
        this.timer = new Timer();
        System.out.println("Starting timer ...");
        int period = 1000;
        this.timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, period);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        TimerTest tt = new TimerTest();
        tt.startTimer();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        tt.cancelTimer(); // you can call this method, as soon as u have a correct answer
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        tt.startTimer(); // you can restart your timer as demanded
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        tt.cancelTimer(); // and cancel it again
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still have a problem. If I do not enter any inputs and time is up, the program would not terminate since it is still waiting for user's inputs. How to show next question or terminate the program when the time is up and there are no inputs?

Comment: Well, thats another question regarding the scanner object. You need to find a way to close the scanner from outside. I know for sure, that you can just call a close method on the scanner. I guess it should close the current user input aswell.

Comment: I tested it. You can in fact use the close method of the scanner object. You have to think about using multiple threads. But again, thats a different question...